# How to use enable and disable property for icons in <i> in angular project. I want to enable and disable the icons on the basis of flag

Tags: html, css, angular

```
      <th style="text-transform: capitalize" *ngFor="let column of columns" key=column?.name
        (click)="handleSort(column?.name)">
        {{column?.thName}}{{" "}}
        <span class="icon-section" style="float:right">

       <i class="fa fa-arrow-up icon" style="color:#696A95"></i>
         

          <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon" style="color:#696A95"></i>
       
         </span>
      </th>
```

Want to enable and disable icons on the basis of flag in table . I want that when someone clicks on arrow up it will sort the table in ascending order and disable the ascending icon and enable the descending icon and vice versa.it is a angular project .the value of flag is changing in handlesort().

Comment: You can't "disable" an icon. You can change its style so that it *appears* disabled (by changing its opacity, for instance), but whether it sorts ascending or descending will be up to your `handleSort()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isIconEnabled">
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Its working but it disables all icons of columns.if i click icon of column 1 then it will disable all the icons of column

Comment: okay then you need to update your logic for example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-ptpiea?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts